# Search rules for dependencies of COM server DLLs

Tags: windows, dll, com

Consider the following file organization on Windows:

```
[app folder]
    app.exe
    [folder 'sub']
        com_server.dll
        regular.dll
        helper.dll
```

Also assume the following:

- Both com_server.dll and regular.dll are statically linked to a function in helper.dll, so that helper.dll is loaded when they are.
- app.exe has no static dependencies.
- The com_server.dll COM objects are registered with Windows
- folder 'sub' is not in the system Path.

Consider the following cases:

1. app.exe calls LoadLibrary( "sub/regular.dll" ). This will fail because Windows will be unable to find helper.dll, consistent with the documented DLL search procedure.
2. app.exe calls CoCreateInstance to create an object implemented in com_server.dll. This succeeds and helper.dll is loaded.

The main questions: Why does case 2 work? What are the details of the dependent DLL search procedure for the COM server case?

It would appear that when creating a com object with CoCreateInstance, the implementing dll's folder is somehow added to the search path for dependencies. Is this what is happening, and is this guaranteed? I cannot find any documentation anywhere that discusses this case.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the documentation for [LoadLibrary on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If the string specifies a full path, the function searches only that path for the module.
>   If the string specifies a relative path or a module name without a path, the function uses a standard search strategy to find the module; for more information, see the Remarks.

Ok, so that explains the behavior of #1 above.  If you had said:

```
LoadLibrary("C:\\program files\\AppFolder\\Sub\\com_server.dll")
```

Then that would have found your dependent DLLs, and LoadLibrary would have succeeded.

As for how COM succeeds with #2, that really depends on how com_server.dll is registered in the registry for the InProcServer32 key.  If it's a full path to the file, then LoadLibrary would just work as described above. If it's a relative path, then I would suspect COM could be doing any number of things to make finding DLLs like yours work.

One likely possibility is that CoCreateInstance is calling [LoadLibraryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the **LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR** flag set.  It may even call LoadLibrary(Ex) multiple times with different combination of flags.

Also, given that CoCreateInstance is a system API, it's entirely possible it has a private internal version of LoadLibrary that allows for alternate search paths.

Comment: You are (mostly) addressing how the system finds the primary DLL requested, not the dependencies of that DLL. Calling 'LoadLibrary("C:\\...\\regular.dll")' still fails because the system can't find helper.dll. I agree that the system may be using LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR in the COM case, but that's unrelated to whether the com dll has an absolute path in the registry. It would be nice to have documentation of that to be sure that if one is distributing a COM library for 3rd party use, one can simply place regular DLL dependencies of the COM dll's in the same folder and that's all.

Comment: Oops, I knew you were referring to dependent DLLs, but I misquoted the wrong docs. Ignore the top half of my answer. I'm fairly that the install directory of a COM DLL is searched for its implicitly linked dependencies.  IIRC, it can get dicey if the COM DLL (or it's dependents) makes a LoadLibrary call on its own with the assumption that the EXE and DLLs are all in the same directory.